# How to store input data with user id in Laravel using eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have four field in database : 
Profile_id (primary Key), user_id, First_name, Last_name

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
    ]);
    $user_id= Auth::user()->id;
    $postdata = $request->all();
    profile::create($postdata);
    return redirect('profile');
}
```

This is storing only First_name and last_name, How to save user id with others.

Comment: You failed to [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment), you need to specify `$fillable` property on your model.

Comment: I have written, I want to know the right query like profile::create($postdata)

Comment: You need to start reading the documentation, its all there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
    'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
]);
$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
$data['first_name'] = $request['first_name'];
$data['last_name'] = $request['last_name'];
profile::create($data);
return redirect('profile');
}
```

Try this way it will store your data

Comment: Is there some way this can be done without necessarily listing the fields?            dbTableName::create($request->all()) can do it. But how to include the logged in user id?